# MYSQL two tables, display within block for each user

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables which are

```
mugallery_2019 table                  |  users table
title | filename | id | author_id     |  user_name | user_id
----------------------------------    |  --------------------
test1 |test1.jpg | 1  | 1             |  tester1   | 1
test2 |test2.jpg | 2  | 2             |  tester2   | 2 
test3 |test3.jpg | 3  | 2             |  tester3   | 3
test4 |test4.jpg | 4  | 1             |
test5 |test5.jpg | 5  | 1
```

My goal is to retrieve data from those tables and display the images grouped by each user on one page.

I have tried many other ways within my knowledge, but they wouldn't work well as I expected.

This is the first one I've tried with two queries.

case 1

```
<div class="test">
<?php 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user_name FROM mugallery_2019 JOIN users ON mugallery_2019.author_id = users.user_id GROUP BY author_id") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <div class="user">
        <h2><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></h2>
        <?php $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, filename, title FROM mugallery_2019") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)): ?>
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="display.php?id=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"><img src="images/thumbs-square/<?php echo $item['filename']; ?>" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

case 1 result

```
tester1
test1.jpg test2.jpg test3.jpg test4.jpg test5.jpg

tester2
test1.jpg test2.jpg test3.jpg test4.jpg test5.jpg
```

And this is other way I've tried with one query

case 2

```
<div class="test">
<?php 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mugallery_2019 JOIN users ON mugallery_2019.author_id = users.user_id GROUP BY author_id") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <div class="user">
        <h2><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></h2>
        <?php
        $title = $row['title'];
        $image = $row['filename'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        if($id == $user_id):?>
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="display.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="images/thumbs-square/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

case 2 result

```
tester 1
test1.jpg
tester 2
test2.jpg
```

It seems like I should progress further with case 2, but I don't know what to do now...

Any help would be much appreciated.

edit) 
desired output

```
tester1
test1.jpg test4.jpg test5.jpg

tester2
test2.jpg test3.jpg
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a `GROUP BY` in your second query. Then you just need to only output the header when `$row['user_name']` is not the same as it was for the previous row

Comment: What exactly is the output you desire? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Nick you mean for case 2 ? Should I use if statement to do so? I honestly can't think of anything to compare value from previous row right now... my brain is dying.

Comment: @Qirel I added my desired output. if possible, I want to have extra feature which is if the user has more than 4 posts, I only want it to display only 4 of them, and the rest to be shown whenever button is clicked. (i didin't make a button yet because I had to figure out this first). Thanks

Comment: @EricHobinYoo yes, case 2. Set a variable `$last_value = '';` before your while loop and then use `if ($row['user_name'] != $last_value)` to control echoing the header, and add `$last_value = $row['user_name']` with all the other assignments from `$row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, where you order the result by the `user_id`, then in PHP check if the user ID has changed between the iterations. When it changes, close the previous block (if it was opened) and display the new header.

You should avoid having a query within a loop when you can avoid it (which this solution avoids)!

```
<div class="test">
    <?php 
    $prev_user = null;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *
                                    FROM mugallery_2019 AS m
                                    JOIN users AS u
                                        ON m.author_id = u.user_id 
                                    ORDER BY u.user_id") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $image = $row['filename'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $user_name = $row['user_name'];

            if ($prev_user !== $user_id) {
                if ($prev_user !== null) {
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                $prev_user = $user_id;
                ?>
                <div class="user">
                    <h2><?= $user_name ?></h2>
                    <?php 
            } ?>
            <div class="thumb">
                <a href="display.php?id=<?= $id; ?>"><img src="images/thumbs-square/<?= $image; ?>" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <?php 
        }
        echo '</div>';
     } ?>
</div>
```

Also, some proper error handling wouldn't be a bad idea. This would display the actual SQL error to the end-user if an error occurred, which is not good. Errors should never be displayed in live production environments.

Comment: It shows the output that are supposed to be displayed. Though, It's in like cascading form with user_name above each image. https://imgur.com/yz47CJc

Comment: Oh shoot, forgot to update the value of `$prev_user`. Hang on! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one more question though. If I want to display only 4 images per user, should I put count ++ thing? or is there any specific technique I could use?

Comment: The best way to go would probably be to limit it in the query, but yes, you can use a counter in PHP too. Reset it where `$prev_user` gets set, and if its above your threshold, use `continue;`.

Comment: I see. I've tried LIMIT, but it would only show four images from the tester1. I think I should try count for this one then. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky, because you have to limit to 4 results per group of user IDs. Unless the dataset is very huge, this would work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

```
$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($users)){
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mugallery_2019 WHERE author_id = {$user['id']}") or 
 die(mysqli_error($con));

    <h2><?php echo $user['user_name']; ?></h2>

    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="display.php?id=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"><img src="images/thumbs-square/<?php echo $item['filename']; ?>" alt=""></a>
        </div>          
    }

    echo "\n</div>";  

}
```

Comment: Wow Thank you. This is by far the best result I've got. It displays as I expected. Though, It would display the user who doesn't have a single post which is tester 3 in this case. How would I be able to hide users who doesn't have post ?

Comment: This uses a query within a loop, which is a bad idea.

Comment: yeah I know, we need to do eager loading for these type of, but for that you need handle more code, but it is fine for small application where performance not matter, for [eager loading in php and mysql](https://kevdees.com/raw-php-and-mysql-eager-loading/) refer this.